# add custom field to image widgert in Drupal

Tags: drupal, widget, field, content-type

I have a content type within which i'm using the Image field type and widget which provides a field for alt text and title. Now I'd like to add another field "link" to each image where I can define a custom link with each image. How can I do this?

Oh, I'm using Drupal 7...

Thanks,
Ron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid having to build your own module, I suggest you try [Field Collection module](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection). The module allows you to create a set of fields, combine it into one field and then use it as a field on `content type`.

You can create a field collection with one `image` field and [`link` field](http://drupal.org/project/link), then output that as an image with link.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this alter function - "`multiupload_imagefield_widget_field_widget_form_alter`"